# Pivot Control ManipulationCompleted

Tags: pivot, windows-phone-8

ManipulationCompleted event doesn't work in WP8 SDK. What would be an alternative way to solve this problem?

Including dectecting swipe right or left, or choose other pivot item by clicking on the pivot header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SelectedIndex to identified selected pivot page. For instance, you can use as:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Resources["AppBar1"]);
            break;
        case 1:
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Resources["AppBar2"]);
            break;
        case 2:
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Resources["AppBar3"]);
            break;
        case 3:
            ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Resources["AppBar4"]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help